# Unable to read a jade form field when it has enctype="multipart/form-data" (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, multipart

I'm using Nodejs + express and I have a form, I need it to upload and image and other data, but the problem is when the form has enctype="multipart/form-data" I can not read the text fields, I don't know how to decrypt the data it contains cause I usually did it using:

```
MYPROJECT.post("/example",function(req,res){
   var name = req.body.name; // or res.param('name')
   console.log(name) // And it works without enctype="multipart/form-data" in form, when it has enctype="multipart/form-data returns undefined 
});
```

Comment: Are you using the proper middleware?

Comment: Post the form, middleware and express version.

Comment: formidable express 4~.2.0

Answer (score 0):

1st When you asking ,put the code sample , so that it will be easy to understand.
 As far i know , when you are posting some data with a file type , you need to have "multer" or any kind of this packages .check the code sample below with sample jada and js file,

```
form(method='post' , action='/users/register',enctype='multipart/form-data')
    .form-group
        label Name
        input.form-control(type='text',name='name', value='' ,placeholder='Enter the Name')
    .form-group
        label Email
        input.form-control(type='email',name='email', placeholder='Enter the Email')
    .form-group
        label Password
        input.form-control(type='password',name='password', placeholder='Enter the Password')
    .form-group
        label Profile Image
        input.form-control(type='file',name='profileimage')
    input.btn.btn-default(name='submit' type='submit',value='Register')

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
router.post('/register',upload.single('avatar'),function(req,res,next){
  //your code
});
```